# Don't understand error I get in Ln 28

Tags: java, loops

I am trying to find the biggest plateau in the array that I have created. For some reason I keep on getting hung up on Ln 28. What am I not seeing or correcting?

```
import java.util.Random;
public class MyAttemptAtPlateauProblem
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Random random = new Random();
  boolean plateau = false;
  int largest = 0;
  int largest_start = 0;
  int array[] = new int[500];
  for (int a = 1; a<array.length; a++)
  {
     array[a]=random.nextInt(20)+1;
     System.out.println(array[a]);
  }
  for ( int a = 1; a < array.length - 1; a++)
     if (!plateau && array[a] == array[a+1] && array[a-1]<array[a])
        {
           plateau = true;
           int start = a-1;
        }else if (plateau && array[a]==array[a+1])
        {
        }else if (plateau && array[a]!=array[a+1])
        {
           if(array[a+1]<array[a])
           {
              int end = a+1;
              if(end- int start+1>largest || (end-start+1==largest && array[largest_start+1]<array[start+1]))
              {
                 largest=end-start+1;
                 largest_start=start;
              }
           }
           plateau=false;
        }

        System.out.println(largest_start + " : " + largest + " : ");
        for(int a=0;a<largest;a++)
        {
           System.out.println(array[largest_start+a] + " - ");
        }
   System.out.println(array);
   }            
}
```

I tried declaring start as a new variable in the loop, but that did nothing, and I think in doing that I will lose the previous value.

Comment: There are no line numbers here, so you might want to specify the actual code which is causing an error.

Comment: Please, don't paste the full code, you know where you caught, so just paste the code of that part.

Answer (score 1):

> if(end- int start+1>largest || (end-start+1==largest &&
>   array[largest_start+1]

because you can't use the keyword 'int' like that. Please do more reading.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SO.

You need to declare `int start` outside of the if statement. However, start will always have the value of 0 if I interpret your code correctly, why is that?